# CakePhP Alaxos plugin error

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

So after a few days of work with ACL and Alaxos i finally got to a point where i can see the end of the tunnel. Everything is setup correctly, when i create a user the user goes into the right group and so on.

Now to manage this ACL i wanted to use the Alaxos plugin and i have manged to install it HOWEVER there is an error:

When i go to /admin/acl i get the correct following view:

[image]

Now when i go to for instance permissions under and under roles i get the next view:
[image]

Now this is fine and all execpt that i cannot edit, modifiy or add any permissions actually this goes for the whole thing i simply cannot touch it other than clearing and building it.

Has anyone tried anything similar or have a solution?

Also please note that if i go under fire bug and try to see what is happening there are images that it cannot load. However its not trying to load these images from the plugins webroot it is trying to load them from the cake webroot.

Comment: Try disabling the ajax features, I have problems with that too sometimes and turning them off makes it work.

Comment: @Oldskool how do i disable those+

Comment: In the Config/bootstrap.php, just set the ajax options (`acl.gui.roles_permissions.ajax` and `acl.gui.users_permissions.ajax`, which are the bottom two settings) to `false` instead of the default `true`.

Comment: @Oldskool the config in app or the config in the plugin?

Comment: The Plugin's bootstrap, your app bootstrap most likely doesn't even have those options.

Comment: @Oldskool Sadly this has no effect :(